# Precompile handlebars and avoid runtime dependency?

Tags: javascript, templates, webpack, handlebars.js, ejs

I've been using EJS to precompile templates and serve a bundled javascript file with no other dependencies, not even EJS itself. It's just a function with pure javascript that takes some arguments and returns the HTML.

I've been trying to do the same thing with handlebars, just to evaluate my possibilites, but it doesn't seem to be possible without bundling handlebars as a runtime dependency.

Is there any way to avoid this? Are there any other popular template engines for javascript with the possibility of no runtime dependency? Preferably with the possibility to write pure HTML, i.e. not pug.

Currently I'm using webpack and I bundle my EJS with this [ejs-compiled-loader](https://github.com/bazilio91/ejs-compiled-loader).

The goal is to write a small package that can output custom html tags and read attributes from these, and then pass to the template and output HTML.